# Pass data between react-native and android

Tags: react-native, sharedpreferences

I need to pass data from react-native to android.

Within react-native, once the user is logged in, I need to get the user ID and store it in memory.
Next time when the app starts, I need to access that user ID from android code and supply it for an sdk for some data processing. I tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-default-preference but couldn't get the value added from react-native from android side.

[image]

And when I was trying to configure react-native default preferences I got [the above error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGPDz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `new RNDefaultPreferencePackage()` from returned package array from MainApplication.java in `getPackages` method

[should be something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ssr0j.png)